# Use of All CAPS in Scala Code

Tags: scala

The common practice in Java is to use all caps for static final variables:

```
static final int MY_CONSTANT = 24
```

I believe the common practice in Scala for `val` is to use:

```
val MyConstant = 24
```

**Is there an accepted place to use all caps, like in Java, in Scala?**

Comment: Mostly off-topic, but I only recently learned that the Java style is called "screaming snake case".

Comment: @TravisBrown sounds scary (lol)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the official guidelines](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html): **no.** In practice `ALL_CAPS` generally means "all caps, separated by underscores," and Scala really doesn't want you using underscores in names.

> Generally speaking, Scala uses “camelCase” naming conventions. That is, each word (except possibly the first) is delimited by capitalizing its first letter. Underscores (`_`) are *heavily* discouraged as they have special meaning within the Scala syntax.